# BroadcastReceiver call Service only once in loop

Tags: android

This is my tts service code:

```
public class SMSTTSService extends Service implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, OnUtteranceCompletedListener {

private TextToSpeech tts;
private String spokenText;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);     
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {        
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

        // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level
        // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
        } else {                
            speakOut(spokenText);
        }

        /*if (result != TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA && result != TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            tts.speak(c, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }*/
    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }
}

private void speakOut(String text) {
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

@Override
public void onUtteranceCompleted(String uttId) {
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}       

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);     
    spokenText = intent.getStringExtra("spoken_txt");
}
```

}

and from receiver i call service like

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "SMSReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++) {
....
 Intent intentTTS = new Intent(context, SMSTTSService.class);
                        intentTTS.putExtra("spoken_txt", msgBody);
                        context.startService(intentTTS);

}
```

but service is executed only one time even if i am having loop. how to make that i will have voice inside loop more than one time? What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use the IntentService class for multiple instances.

Refer to this: [Multiple IntentService or one Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333822/multiple-intentservice-or-one-service)

**Edit:** This is a quick example showing strict necessary code about IntentService:

```
public class ExampleIntentService extends IntentService {
     private static final String TAG = ExampleIntentService.class.getName();

     public ExampleIntentService() {
          super(TAG);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

          // The code you want to execute
     }
}
```

In order to start the service, you do for example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SYNC, null, context, ExampleIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra(ExampleIntentService.EXTRA_DATA, "some data");
        context.startService(intent);
```

Then, in the manifest you add:

```
<service android:name="your.package.services.ExampleIntentService" />
```

Now if you want more details and combined usage with BroadcastReceiver, I found these links from the first results of google:

- http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-intentservice-example-using.html
- http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/

Comment: is there any other option then with services?

Comment: IntentService is a service, you start the same way, using context.startService(intent). You just have to make a few modifications on your SMSTTSService class to extends IntentService, not a big deal I think.

Comment: thank you for updated code but ExampleIntentService class is never executed

Comment: I just tested to be sure and everything is fine on my side. If I put a Log.d() inside the onHandleIntent() method, and start the service using this.startService(intent) from an activity for example, it starts correctly the service and prints my log. Make sure to add the service to your Manifest.xml, and please take a look to the examples links I provided, they are far more useful than my ridiculous little example. I just wanted to introduce the concept to you.

Comment: thank you i will tested again and i am going to read links again too.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onStart()` method is being called many times, but all it does is set the `spokenText` variable to the passed extra. All this happens while the first Intent is being spoken. Then you shut the service down.

What you probably want to do is to implement a simple queue. In the `onStart()` method extract the extra and add the spokenText to the queue. Then start processing the queue (if it isn't already being processed).

When processing the queue, remove the first element in the queue and start speaking that. In the `onUtteranceCompleted()` method, remove the first element in the queue and, if there is one, start speaking that one. When no elements are in the queue, stop the service.

Should work.

Comment: hmm thank you but what about next time when receiver will be called. service is never executed any more...